# Polygonal numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory

A polygonal number is the number of dots in a `k`-gon of size `n`.

You will be given `n` and `k`, and your task is to write a program/function that outputs/prints the corresponding number.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes wins.

## Example

[image: 3rd hexagon number]

The `3`rd hexagon number (`k=6, n=3`) is `28` because there are `28` dots above.

## Testcases

Can be generated from [this Pyth test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JEsmh*dttJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=10%0A3%0A10%0A4%0A10%0A5%0A100%0A3%0A1000%0A24&debug=0&input_size=2).

Usage: two lines per testcase, `n` above, `k` below.

```
n    k  output
10   3  55
10   5  145
100  3  5050
1000 24 10990000
```

## Further information

- In Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number
- In Wolfram Mathworld: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonalNumber.html
- In OEIS Wiki: http://oeis.org/wiki/Polygonal_numbers
- OEIS sequences for **n**-gonal numbers for various **n**: **3** [(A000217)](http://oeis.org/A000217), **4** [(A000290)](http://oeis.org/A000290), **5** [(A000326)](http://oeis.org/A000326), **6** [(A000384)](http://oeis.org/A000384), **7** [(A000566)](http://oeis.org/A000566), **8** [(A000567)](http://oeis.org/A000567), **9** [(A001106)](http://oeis.org/A001106), **10** [(A001107)](http://oeis.org/A001107), **11** [(A051682)](http://oeis.org/A051682), **12** [(A051624)](http://oeis.org/A051624), **13** [(A051865)](http://oeis.org/A051865), **14** [(A051866)](http://oeis.org/A051866), **15** [(A051867)](http://oeis.org/A051867), **16** [(A051868)](http://oeis.org/A051868), **17** [(A051869)](http://oeis.org/A051869), **18** [(A051870)](http://oeis.org/A051870), **19** [(A051871)](http://oeis.org/A051871), **20** [(A051872)](http://oeis.org/A051872), **21** [(A051873)](http://oeis.org/A051873), **22** [(A051874)](http://oeis.org/A051874), **23** [(A051875)](http://oeis.org/A051875), **24** [(A051876)](http://oeis.org/A051876)

Comment: Isn't that the 4th hexagonal number in the picture?

Comment: @Neil We count from zero.

Comment: You really are going on a question posting spree, aren't you?

Comment: The example might be off. If you put `n=3` and `k=6` into your test suite, you get `15`. If you put in `n=4` and `k=6`, you get `28`.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
’;’;PH+
```

This uses the formula

[image: formula]

to compute the **n**<sup>th</sup> **s**-gonal number.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCZO-KAmTtQSCs&input=&args=MjQ+MTAwMA)

#### How it works

```
’;’;PH+  Main link. Arguments: s, n

’        Decrement; yield s - 1.
 ;       Concatenate; yield [s - 1, n].
  ’      Decrement; yield [s - 2, n - 1].
   ;     Concatenate; yield [s - 2, n - 1, n].
    P    Product; yield (s - 2)(n - 1)n.
     H   Halve; yield (s - 2)(n - 1)n ÷ 2.
      +  Add; yield (s - 2)(n - 1)n ÷ 2 + n.
```

Answer (score 4):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), 25 bytes

```
?(({"+!@/"*'+{/?('*})/2':
```

Unfolded:

```
   ? ( ( {
  " + ! @ /
 " * ' + { /
? ( ' * } ) /
 2 ' : . . .
  . . . . .
   . . . .
```

Reads `k` first and `n` second (using any separator).

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAgPyAoICggewogICIgKyAhIEAgLwogIiAqICcgKyB7IC8KPyAoICcgKiB9ICkgLwogMiAnIDogLiAuIC4KICAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgLiAuIC4gLg&input=MjQgMTAwMA)

#### Explanation

The program is completely linear, but as usual in Hexagony, the order of execution is all over the place:

[image]

The paths are executed in the order *grey*, *dark blue*, *red*, *light blue*, *dark green*, *pink*. As you can see, the three `/` only act to redirect the flow. Also, the `.` are no-ops. Stripping all hexagonal fanciness, the resulting linear program is:

```
?(({?('*})"*'+{2':"+!@
```

This computes the standard formula

[image: formula]

like most of the other answers. It does so using the following five memory edges, with the memory pointer (MP) starting as shown in red:

[image]

Here's how this is done:

```
?    Read integer input s into edge A.
((   Decrement twice to get (s-2).
{    Move the MP forwards onto edge B.
?    Read integer input n into edge B.
(    Decrement to get (n-1).
'    Move the MP backwards onto edge C.
*    Multiply edges A and B to store the result (s-2)(n-1) in edge C.
}    Move the MP forwards onto edge B.
)    Increment to restore the value n.
"    Move the MP backwards onto edge A.
*    Multiply edge B and C to store the result (s-2)(n-1)n in edge A.
'    Move the MP backwards onto edge D.
+    Add edges E (initially 0) and A to copy (s-2)(n-1)n into edge D.
{    Move the MP forwards onto edge E.
2    Set the memory edge to value 2.
'    Move the MP backwards onto edge A.
:    Divide edge D by edge E to store (s-2)(n-1)n/2 in edge A.
"    Move the MP backwards onto edge C.
+    Add edges A and B to store (s-2)(n-1)n/2+n in edge C.
!    Print as integer.
@    Terminate the program.
```

Comment: Such a simple formula... requires 25 bytes?!

Comment: @KennyLau This *is* Hexagony after all...

Comment: Hexagony meta question

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

Code:

```
D<LOIÍ*+
```

Explanation:

```
D         # Duplicate the input
 <LO      # Compute n × (n - 1) / 2
    IÍ    # Compute k - 2
      *   # Multiply, resulting into (k - 2)(n - 1)(n) / 2
       +  # Add, resulting into n + (k - 2)(n - 1)(n) / 2
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RDxMT0nDjSor&input=MTAKNQ).

Answer (score 3):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 13 bytes

```
?::(*?((*#/+!
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=Pzo6KCo_KCgqIy8rIQ&input=MTAwMCAyNA)

#### Explanation

Due to its single-character commands (which are merely a necessity of the 2D-ness of the language), Labyrinth can be surprisingly golfy for linear programs.

This uses the same formula as several other answers:

[image: formula]

```
Op  Explanation                 Stack
?   Read n.                     [n]
::  Make two copies.            [n n n]
(   Decrement.                  [n n (n-1)]
*   Multiply.                   [n (n*(n-1))]
?   Read s.                     [n (n*(n-1)) s]
((  Decrement twice.            [n (n*(n-1)) (s-2)]
*   Multiply.                   [n (n*(n-1)*(s-2))]
#   Push stack depth, 2.        [n (n*(n-1)*(s-2)) 2]
/   Divide.                     [n (n*(n-1)*(s-2))/2]
+   Add.                        [(n+(n*(n-1)*(s-2))/2)]
!   Print.                      []
```

At this point, the instruction pointer hits a dead end and turns around. Now `+` is executed again, which is a no-op (since the bottom of the stack is implicitly filled with an infinite amount of zeros), and then `/` attempts a division-by-zero which terminates the program with an error.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
(k,n)=>n+n*--n*(k-2)/2
```

Explanation: Each n-gon can be considered to be n points along one side plus k-2 triangles of size n-1, i.e. n+n(n-1)(k-2)/2.

Comment: `k--*n--+2-n` haven't tested though

Comment: @KennyLau Sorry, but `(k,n)=>n*(--k*--n-n+2)/2` is still 24 bytes.

Comment: @KennyLau In fact I overlooked the obvious use of `--n` for `(n-1)`. D'oh!

Comment: @NeiI Well, nice.

Comment: You can save a bye with currying: `k=>n=>n+n*--n*(k-2)/2`

Comment: @Dennis I'm too lazy to curry any of my answers.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 13 bytes

```
q~__(*2/@2-*+
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cX5fXygqMi9AMi0qKw&input=MjQgMTAwMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Thanks to Adám for his help for suggesting this alternate version.

```apl
⊢+-∘2⍤⊣×2!⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HXIm3dRx0zjB71LnnUtfjwdCNFoND/tEdtEx719j3qm@rp/6ir@dB640dtE4G84CBnIBni4Rn831jBRMFMIe3QCgULIMvQAAA)

**Explanation**

```apl
⊢+-∘2⍤⊣×2!⊢  Right argument (⊢) is n. Left argument (⊣) is s.

        2!⊢  Binomial(n, 2) == n*(n-1)/2.
  -∘2⍤⊣×     Multiply (×) with by getLeftArgument (⊢) with (⍤) minus 2 (-∘2) called on it.
             In short, multiply binomial(n,2) with (s-2).
⊢+           Add n.
```

---

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Thanks to Adám for his help in golfing this.

Edit: -1 byte from ngn.

```apl
⊢+{⍺-2}×2!⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXIu3qR727dI1qD083UgRy/6c9apvwqLfvUd9UT/9HXc2H1hs/apsI5AUHOQPJEA/P4P/GCiYKZgpph1YoWABZhgYA)

**Ungolfing**

```apl
⊢+{⍺-2}×2!⊢  Right argument (⊢) is n. Left argument (⊣) is s.

        2!⊢  Binomial(n, 2) == n*(n-1)/2.
  {⍺-2}×     Multiply it by s-2.
⊢+           Add n.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 12 bytes

```
3@n(¬@D3╟π½+
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=M0BuKMKsQEQz4pWfz4DCvSs&input=MwoxMA)

Explanation:

```
3@n(¬@D3╟π½+
3@n           push 3 copies of n (stack: [n, n, n, k])
   (¬         bring k to front and subtract 2 ([k-2, n, n, n])
     @D       bring an n to front and subtract 1 ([n-1, k-2, n, n])
       3╟π    product of top 3 elements ([n*(n-1)*(k-2), n])
          ½   divide by 2 ([n*(n-1)*(k-2)/2, n])
           +  add ([n*(n-1)*(k-2)/2 + n])
```

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 14 bytes

```
?dd1-*2/?2-*+p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98@JcVQV8tI395IV0u74P9/IzMuUwA)

#### Explanation

This makes use of the following formula 
(note that **T**<sub>n</sub> = `n*(n-1)/2`):

[image: Polygonal numbers]

```
                # inputs              | N S                  | 10 5
?dd             # push N three times  | N, N, N              | 10, 10, 10
   1-           # subtract 1          | (N-1), N, N          | 9, 10, 10
     *          # multiply            | (N-1)*N, N           | 90, 10
      2/        # divide by two       | (N-1)*N/2, N         | 45, 10
        ?       # push S              | S, (N-1)*N/2, N      | 5, 45, 10
         2-     # subtract 2          | (S-2), (N-1)*N/2, N  | 3, 45, 10
           *    # multiply            | (S-2)*(N-1)*N/2, N   | 135, 10
            +   # add                 | (S-2)*(N-1)*N/2 + N  | 145
             p  # print to stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), <s>18</s> 15 bytes

Port of the [Bruce Forte's dc answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143893/21173):

```
riddD*2/ri2-*+p
```

Saved 3 bytes by realizing that any "pure" (no combined commands) Aceto program can be written linearly.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 8 bytes

```
_┐*½?⌡*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/@0ZQJWof22j/qWail/f@/oYGCMReQMAUSECaQMjL5DwA)

### Explanation (with \$n = 10, k = 5\$

```
_          duplicate first implicit input, stack is [10, 10]
 ┐         push TOS-1 without popping, stack is [10, 10, 9]
  *        multiply, stack is [10, 90]
   ½       halve TOS, stack is [10, 45]
    ?      rotate top 3 stack elements, popping k to the top: [10, 45, 5]
     ⌡     decrement TOS twice: [10, 45, 3]
      *    multiply: [10, 135]
       +   add: [145]
```

An alternative 8-byter is `┼┐*½\⌡*+`, which takes the input in reversed order.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 13 bytes

```
::1-*2,{2-*+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38rKUFfLSKfaSFdLO@////@6ZQpGJiDS0MDAAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
(#2-2)#(#-1)/2+#&
```

Straight-forward application of the formula.

### Usage

```
  f = (#2-2)#(#-1)/2+#&
  f[10, 3]
55
  f[10, 5]
145
  f[100, 3]
5050
  f[1000, 24]
10990000
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 14 bytes

```
]++/@i.@]*[-2:
```

Based on the formula.

```
P(k, n) = (k - 2) * T(n - 1) + n where T(n) = n * (n + 1) / 2
        = (k - 2) * n * (n - 1) / 2 + n
```

### Usage

```
   f =: ]++/@i.@]*[-2:
   3 f 10
55
   5 f 10
145
   3 f 100
5050
   24 f 1000
10990000
```

### Explanation

```
]++/@i.@]*[-2:
            2:  The constant function 2
          [     Get k
           -    Subtract to get k-2
        ]       Get n
     i.@        Make a range from 0 to n-1
  +/@           Sum the range to get the (n-1) Triangle number = n*(n-1)/2
                The nth Triangle number is also the sum of the first n numbers
         *      Multiply n*(n-1)/2 with (k-2)
]               Get n
 +              Add n to (k-2)*n*(n-1)/2
```

Comment: How long would it be, using my approach?

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 20 bytes

```
Prompt K,N:(K-2)N(N-1)/2+N
```

Answer (score 0):

## GameMaker Language, 44 bytes

```
n=argument1;return (argument0-2)*n*(n-1)/2+n
```

Comment: Is the space required?

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 28 bytes

The straight up equation from [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number)

```
lambda s,n:(s-2)*(n-1)*n/2+n
```

*Thanks to @Mego for saving a byte!*

Comment: You can remove the space between the colon and the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
-[U½UÉVÍ]×
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=LVtVvVXJVs1d1w&input=MTAsMw)

Answer (score 0):

## Fourier, 18 bytes

```
I-2~SI~Nv*N/2*S+No
```

[**Try it on FourIDE!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/editor/?code=SS0yflNJfk52Kk4vMipTK05v)

Takes k as first input and n as second input. Uses the formula:

[image]

***Explanation Pseudocode:***

```
S = Input - 2
N = Input
Print (N - 1) * N / 2 *S + N
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel,  22 bytes

Calculates the `A1`th `B1`-gonal number.

```
=(B1-2)*A1*(A1-1)/2+A1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 21 bytes

All individual answers of equal byte-length:

```java
k->n->n+n*~-n*(k-2)/2
k->n->n+n*--n*(k-2)/2
k->n->n+n*~-n*~-~-k/2
k->n->n+n*--n*~-~-k/2
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lY4xD4IwEIV3fsWNoLYq6oQymjg4MRqHWpAUytHAYWKM/nUsSQc2MblLXvK@u/cK8RCsNhkWadlLLdoWzkLhywNoSZCSUFiCd6Q0v3coSdXIj07sT0hZnjWLaZATcQwSDn3JYrQzx9mHDfth5TLsI88mm@6mbbIr8KhVCpUt5SfUKMwvVxDBUBAgebaUVbzuiBtrkUZfcmGMfvqbwIn1KgiiX/TuL3r0ewoebke8O3h77/4L)

```java
k->n->            // Method with two integer parameters and integer return-type
  n+              //  Return `n` plus
    n*            //   `n` multiplied by
      ~-n         //   `n-1`
         *(k-2)   //   Multiplied by `k-2`
               /2 //   Divided by 2
                  // End of method (implicit / single-line return-statement)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
S+~*-2(Σ←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1i7TkvXSOPc4kdtE/7//2/639AAAA)

#### Explanation

Using the same formula as in my `dc` answer:

[image: Polygonal numbers]

```
            -- implicit inputs S, N                     | 5, 10
S+          -- compute N + the result of the following  | 10 + 
  ~*        --   multiply these two together            |      (   ) * 
    -2      --     S-2                                  |       S-2
      (Σ←)  --     triangle number of (N-1)             |              tri(N-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 16 char, 32 bytes

```
{⍵+(⍺-2)×+/⍳⍵-1}
```

It is based from the fact that seems n×(n-1)/2=sum(1..n-1) test:

```
  f←{⍵+(⍺-2)×+/⍳⍵-1}
  10 f 3
27
  3 f 10
55
  5 f 19
532
  3 f 10
55
  5 f 10
145
  3 f 100
5050
  24 f 1000
10990000
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 67 bytes

```
listen to N
listen to K
cast N
let K be-2
let K be*N-1
say K*.5*N+N
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in, with each input integer on an individual line)

Answer (score 0):

## x86-16 machine code, 14 bytes

```
00000000: 4949 8bc3 48f7 e3f7 e1d1 e803 c3c3       II..H.........
```

Listing:

```
49          DEC  CX         ; k = k - 2 
49          DEC  CX 
8B C3       MOV  AX, BX     ; AX = n 
48          DEC  AX         ; AX = n - 1 
F7 E3       MUL  BX         ; AX = n * n - 1 
F7 E1       MUL  CX         ; AX = ( k - 2 ) * n * ( n - 1 ) 
D1 E8       SHR  AX, 1      ; AX = ( k - 2 ) * n * ( n - 1 ) / 2 
03 C3       ADD  AX, BX     ; AX = ( ( k - 2 ) * n * ( n - 1 ) / 2 ) + n
C3          RET             ; return to caller
```

Callable function, input `n` in `BX`, `k` in `CX`, result in `AX`.